# equality operator for numbers and alpha-numbers in perl

Tags: perl, operators

I am reading a file which contains thousands of lines.
I am reading the file line by line.
After I read the line, using `substr` I am fetching 2 values for 2 variables as shown below.

```
$val1 = substr($line,15,3);
$val2 = substr($line,18,3);
```

Now I want to check whether these two values are equal. `$val1` can just be a number (like 233) or it can be alphanumeric (like V23) which varies from line to line. I am neither able to use `==` operator nor `eq` operator. Please give me a suggestion how to solve this problem.

To make it clear consider below example.
  After reading first line val1=235 and val2=236 .Here if I use eq it returns true SO I will have to use ==.
  After reading second line val1=v26 and val2=v26. Here I can't use == as it is alphanumric.I need to use eq.

so how to write program for this?

Comment: Why can't you use `eq`?

Comment: If one of  the operands to `eq` is a number Perl will coerce it to a string.

Comment: To clarify, should `2.0` be equal to `2  `? (the character `2` followed by two spaces)

Comment: You hinted that your definition of equal differs from `==`'s and from `eq`'s, but you didn't specify what it is. This question is missing a key component!

Comment: Is this an academic exercice? In real world you would use "eq" for that. If it is academic, you are suposed to implement your wown string comparing function...

Comment: No I am writing a perl application which requires to read the file.Please see the question I have added more information.

Comment: `235 eq 236` does not return true.

Answer (score 1):

possible solution..

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);

my $val1 = '233';
my $val2 = 'V23';

if ( looks_like_number($val1) && looks_like_number($val2) )
{
    print "both values are numbers.";
    if ( $val1 == $val2 )
    {
        print "numeric values are equivalent.";
    }else{
        print "numeric values are not equivalent.";
    }
}
elsif ( !looks_like_number($val1) && !looks_like_number($val2) )
{
    print "both values are strings.";
    if ( $val1 eq $val2 )
    {
        print "string values are equivalent.";
    }else{
        print "string values are not equivalent.";
    }
}
else
{
    print "the variables are not of the same type.";
}
```